# What is Facebook's IM server Address and Port?

Tags: android, facebook, xmpp, instant-messaging

I would like to create my own chat client for Facebook IM in Android. I created XMPP Jabber protocol in Java but I dont know the host name and port number of Facebook IM server. Can any one let me know the Facebook's IM server host name and port number to communicate?

Comment: if you only want to know the host and port for facebooks im server (which has nothing to do with android) you might want to change your title and tags to ask for what you actually want to know. especially the android-tag will probably get a lot of people who potentionally might know this, to not read the question, because they're not into android. also, there's a lot to "how to create IM client" that is not about knowing which server to connect to. I think you might scare people away by chooseing title and tags that looks like you're asking for help with a thousand lines of android code =)

Comment: You can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11238124/1472665 answer, which can solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook Chat now supports (limited) XMPP. The server name is chat.facebook.com and the port number is 5222 as per usual.

Answer (score 3):

First, download [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) (XMPP client library for Java).
Facebook XMPP Server is: chat.facebook.com, port = 5222

Facebook Chat fully support XMPP so you can see how conversation is done using XMPP and smack and add Facebook to it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware Facebook doesn't use the jabber protocol for its chat.  My guess is that it wouldn't make any sense for them to since they offer it as an AJAX application within the Facebook website so the traffic is going to HTTP/HTTPS and not XMPP.

Interaction with Facebook is through the Facebook APIs.  Unfortunately, there is no official API for Chat.

Some people have done some work [reverse engineering Facebook Chat](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=facebook+chat+api&meta=) so you might have some luck there.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some work with parsing Facebook chat, and it is done in cleartext in the the form of [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)) Tuples.  Get a copy of wireshark and you can easily see the traffic passed back a forth.

Comment: Or now that they officially support XMPP, it's much simpler.

Answer (score -3):

Facebook Chat Server is: chat.facebook.com, port = 5222.
Some time before some apps like ebuddy were able to access it but i think now it is only limited to facebook messenger.

Comment: This has already been stated several times, and adds nothing. Upvoting the similar answers would be the proper way of indicating what is a good solution.