# Android Facebook chat example project

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-chat

I found sample **Facebook Chat Project**  for iOS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035636/how-to-make-facebook-chat).

also i got the **facebook chat doc** [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/)

Same way,

Did any one know facebook chat example app or way to implement fb chat in android?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is one Android Open Source Project available : [Beem Project](http://beem-project.com/) and For connecting Facebook chat you can used following guidelines.

**Steps for implementing Facebook chat API in Android:**

1. First we have to implement [MemorizingTrustManager](https://github.com/ge0rg/MemorizingTrustManager) Library project in existing project.

   => For that you have to copy following three files in existing project

   - MemorizingTrustManager/src/de/duenndns/ssl/MTMDecision.java
   - MemorizingTrustManager/src/de/duenndns/ssl/MemorizingActivity.java
   - MemorizingTrustManager/src/de/duenndns/ssl/MemorizingTrustManager.java

   => And add following values in **values/string.xml**

   ```
   <resources>
       <string name="mtm_accept_cert">Accept Unknown Certificate?</string>
       <string name="mtm_decision_always">Always</string>
       <string name="mtm_decision_once">Once</string>
       <string name="mtm_decision_abort">Abort</string>
       <string name="mtm_notification">Certificate Verification</string>
   </resources>
   ```
2. Second step, Instead of using **SASLAuthentication** such as **X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM**, You can used following code to connect with Facebook and login using your **Facebook Jabber ID (username@chat.facebook.com)**

   ```
   public void connectToFb() throws XMPPException {

   ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
   config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
   config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.required);
   config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(true);
   config.setTruststorePath("/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks");
   config.setTruststorePassword("changeit");
   config.setTruststoreType("bks");
   config.setSendPresence(false);
   try {
       SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
       sc.init(null, MemorizingTrustManager.getInstanceList(this), new java.security.SecureRandom());
       config.setCustomSSLContext(sc);
   } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
       Log.w("TAG", "Unable to use MemorizingTrustManager", e);
   }
   XMPPConnection xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
   try {
       xmpp.connect();
       xmpp.login("facebookusername", "****"); // Here you have to used only facebookusername from facebookusername@chat.facebook.com
       Roster roster = xmpp.getRoster();
       Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
       System.out.println("Connected!");
       System.out.println("\n\n" + entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
       // shows first time onliners---->
       String temp[] = new String[50];
       int i = 0;
       for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
           String user = entry.getUser();
           Log.i("TAG", user);
       }
   } catch (XMPPException e) {
       xmpp.disconnect();
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
   ```

At last, If you get all the Buddy list of your Facebook account in LogCat View, than you can implement simple Facebook chat using [this tutorial](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/).

Comment: i have accepted the answer but till any other answer is there new answer is welcomed ;-)

Comment: I tried this method but it only returns a list of random numbers that seems to be in some way associated with my buddies? any idea?

Comment: @Dipali I m getting getAppKeyStore(/data/data/com.example.facebookchatdemo/app_KeyStore/KeyStore.bks) - file does not exist, How to resolve this. please help for Upvote :)

Comment: Thanks alot....:) 
Would you please tell me , how to check presence of friends here?

Comment: "For that you have to copy following three files in existing project", to where copy them????