# Facebook connectivity using Jabber ID

Tags: android, facebook, xmpp, asmack

In my app, Instead of using SASLAuthentication such as X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM, I'm using Facebook Jabber ID method for login.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11238124) reference, I got the following piece of code

```
public void connectToFb() throws XMPPException {

ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.required);
config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(true);
config.setTruststorePath("/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks");
config.setTruststorePassword("changeit");
config.setTruststoreType("bks");
config.setSendPresence(false);
try {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sc.init(null, MemorizingTrustManager.getInstanceList(this), new java.security.SecureRandom());
    config.setCustomSSLContext(sc);
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    Log.w("TAG", "Unable to use MemorizingTrustManager", e);
}
XMPPConnection xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
try {
    xmpp.connect();
    xmpp.login("facebookusername", "****"); // Error on this line
    Roster roster = xmpp.getRoster();
    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
    System.out.println("Connected!");
    System.out.println("\n\n" + entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
    // shows first time onliners---->
    String temp[] = new String[50];
    int i = 0;
    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
        String user = entry.getUser();
        Log.i("TAG", user);
    }
} catch (XMPPException e) {
    xmpp.disconnect();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I used **smack 3.3.0** api, uses_INTERNET permission, and the steps mentioned there(MemorizingTrustManager).

But I'm getting error.

```
04-21 15:18:44.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2811): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 15:18:44.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2811): java.lang.VerifyError: org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism
04-21 15:18:44.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2811):     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Native Method)
04-21 15:18:44.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2811):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:472)
04-21 15:18:44.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2811):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:314)
04-21 15:18:44.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2811):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:221)
04-21 15:18:44.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2811):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:366)
04-21 15:18:44.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2811):     at com.activapps.fbchat.MainActivity.connectToFb(MainActivity.java:61)
```

Having profile like www.facebook.com/*nizam.cs* ; I used user id as nizam.cs, nizam.cs@facebook.com & nizam.cs@chat.facebook.com for login but none of those worked.

What am I missing?

I tested it on emulator without a facebook sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! :)

The problem was with the smack library that I used. Instead of smack3.3.0, used **asmack-android-6.jar** ***which is an update SMACK library: smack with xep0280 and xep0184***.

That solved the connectivity problem.