# How do I implement facebook chat using aSmack XMPP library in Android (2014)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, chat

I searched many places to find ways to integrate facebook chat into Android/[Smack](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack) but none of them worked completely. Could someone provide **a working example** that works with  the latest version of the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticating using **X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM** SASLAuthentication. Verified working on 14 Jan 2014 with Android 4.2.2.

The jabber ID is *not* username@chat.facebook.com. It is resolved to a numeric id that you can check against the roster.

---

**ChatActivity.java**

```
public void connectToFb() throws XMPPException {        
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
        SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM",SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.class);
        SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", 0);
        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.required);
        config.setSendPresence(false);
        XMPPConnection xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
        try {
            xmpp.connect();
            xmpp.login(Session.getActiveSession().getApplicationId(), Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken(), "Application");

            //send a chat message           
            ChatManager chatmanager = xmpp.getChatManager();
            Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("<jabber-id-here>@chat.facebook.com", new MessageListener() {
                @Override
                public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message msg) {
                    Log.d("test", "message sent = "+ msg);
                }
            });
            newChat.sendMessage("Cowdy!");    

            //get roster  
            Roster roster = xmpp.getRoster();
            Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
            System.out.println("Connected!");
            System.out.println("\n\n" + entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
            for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                Log.i("test", entry.getName());
                Log.i("test", entry.getUser());
            }
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            xmpp.disconnect();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.java**

```
public class SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism extends SASLMechanism {

        public static final String NAME = "X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM";
        private String apiKey = "";
        private String accessToken = "";


        /**
         * Constructor.
         */
        public SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism(SASLAuthentication saslAuthentication) {
            super(saslAuthentication);
        }

        @Override
        protected void authenticate() throws IOException, XMPPException {
            // Send the authentication to the server
            getSASLAuthentication().send(new AuthMechanism(getName(), ""));
        }

        @Override
        public void authenticate(String apiKey, String host, String accessToken) throws IOException, XMPPException {
            this.apiKey = apiKey;
            this.accessToken = accessToken;
            this.hostname = host;

            String[] mechanisms = { "DIGEST-MD5" };
            Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
            this.sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, this);
            authenticate();
        }

        @Override
        protected String getName() {
            return NAME;
        }

        @Override
        public void challengeReceived(String challenge) throws IOException {
            byte[] response = null;

            if (challenge != null) {
                String decodedChallenge = new String(Base64.decode(challenge));
                Map<String, String> parameters = getQueryMap(decodedChallenge);

                String version = "1.0";
                String nonce = parameters.get("nonce");
                String method = parameters.get("method");

                long callId = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() / 1000L;

                String composedResponse = "api_key=" + URLEncoder.encode(apiKey, "utf-8")
                        + "&call_id=" + callId
                        + "&method=" + URLEncoder.encode(method, "utf-8")
                        + "&nonce=" + URLEncoder.encode(nonce, "utf-8")
                        + "&access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode(accessToken, "utf-8")
                        + "&v=" + URLEncoder.encode(version, "utf-8");

                response = composedResponse.getBytes("utf-8");
            }

            String authenticationText = "";

            if (response != null){
                authenticationText = Base64.encodeBytes(response, Base64.DONT_BREAK_LINES);
            }
            // Send the authentication to the server
            getSASLAuthentication().send(new Response(authenticationText));
        }

        private Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query) {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String[] params = query.split("\\&");

            for (String param : params) {
                String[] fields = param.split("=", 2);
                map.put(fields[0], (fields.length > 1 ? fields[1] : null));
            }
            return map;
        }
    }
```

---

**Authentication flow using SASL/Plain (when username and password are supplied)**

Refer to [Android Facebook chat example project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946508/android-facebook-chat-example-project)