# How to get Facebook chat list from Facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook

I want to make a Facebook chat android application. I download the new Facebook SDK for android. But I don't know how to get it to work. Can any one help me....?

Comment: Your question is duplicate. see this link. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11238124/3247356

Answer (score 1):

There are docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat but be aware that the Chat API is deprecated and will be removed at April 30th 2015.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_chat